# increase length of a \node option and change its color

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, color

I would like to increase the vertical length of a node in a way that it can also stretch outside of my image. Moreover, I need to choose different color for each line.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx} % more modern
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\vspace{0.5cm}
\centering
\begin {tikzpicture}
\begin {axis}[
title=LastFM,
width=\textwidth,
height=5cm,
grid=both,
unbounded coords=discard,
ylabel=Distance,
xlabel=Days,
]
\addplot+[color=black,sharp plot, mark=none] coordinates{(1,123.247718031613)    (2,111.79445424528)(3,117.439346047226)(4,111.588529876507)(5,110.715852523476)(6,107.172757732551)(7,114.908659377786)(8,129.313572373514)(9,133.656275572829)(10,138.246157270284)(11,125.865007051205)(12,128.171759760097)(13,108.148046676766)(14,119.063008529098)(15,120.166551086398)(16,108.554133960895)(17,128.241958812239)(18,125.650308395961)(19,122.237473795886)(20,110)(21,107.990740343791)(22,113.877126763894)(23,125.283678106927)(24,130.107647738325)(25,131.818056426273)(26,134.476763792114)(27,101.133575038164)(28,119.674558699834)(29,116.952982005591)(30,117.413798166996)(31,110.571244001323)(32,104.019228991567)(33,95.9374796416917)(34,103.923048454133)};
\node[coordinate,pin=above:{10}] at (axis cs:16,128.241958812239) {};
\node[coordinate,pin=above:{10}] at (axis cs:37,117.524465538032) {};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig}
\caption{My Results}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks buddy for your reply! However, I'm afraid to tell you that `clip=false` didn't change anything! Regarding my second question, I meant the two vertical lines that I indicated with label "10". I want each vertical lines to have different color, for instance the first vertical line in time 16 would have a green color and the second one in time 37 has a blue color and so on.
If you take a quick glance at the following paper in page 2, I bet you'll get what I mean with all these words!
[helpful link!](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/class/cis4930fa07dm/project/GraphScope.pdf)

Answer (score 3):

*Answer the Unanswered*...

You can use different coordinate systems such as `axis cs`, `axis coordinate cs:` etc. Please check the manual for even more systems. Here is a slightly overkill solution to demonstrate different options. To be able to extend the drawing area the clipping action of the axes must be turned off for this solution via `clip=false`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin {tikzpicture}
\begin {axis}[
title=LastFM,
width=\textwidth,
height=5cm,
grid=both,
unbounded coords=discard,
ylabel=Distance,
xlabel=Days,
clip=false
]
\addplot+[color=black,sharp plot, mark=none] coordinates{(1,123.247718031613)    (2,111.79445424528)(3,117.439346047226)(4,111.588529876507)(5,110.715852523476)(6,107.172757732551)(7,114.908659377786)(8,129.313572373514)(9,133.656275572829)(10,138.246157270284)(11,125.865007051205)(12,128.171759760097)(13,108.148046676766)(14,119.063008529098)(15,120.166551086398)(16,108.554133960895)(17,128.241958812239)(18,125.650308395961)(19,122.237473795886)(20,110)(21,107.990740343791)(22,113.877126763894)(23,125.283678106927)(24,130.107647738325)(25,131.818056426273)(26,134.476763792114)(27,101.133575038164)(28,119.674558699834)(29,116.952982005591)(30,117.413798166996)(31,110.571244001323)(32,104.019228991567)(33,95.9374796416917)(34,103.923048454133)};
\draw[red,shorten <=-5mm] ({axis cs:16,120} |- {axis description cs:0,0}) -- ([yshift=5mm]{{axis cs:16,120} |- {axis description cs:0,1}}) node[above] {$10$};
\draw[green,shorten <=-5mm] ({axis cs:37,120} |- {axis description cs:0,0}) -- ([yshift=5mm]{{axis cs:37,120} |- {axis description cs:0,1}}) node[above] {$10$};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\label{fig}
\caption{My Results}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]